# Why does my iPhone's audio when played over Bluetooth stop when the display turns off?

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth

I've paired a Bluetooth headset to my iPhone and when I try to listen to music over Bluetooth with the display off, the audio stops when the display goes off, most of the time. Why is this? It makes the Bluetooth stereo audio of the phone pretty useless. I'm running iPhone OS 3.0, which added this feature.

I've tried both a Plantronics and Jabra stereo bluetooth headset, so I doubt it's the headset.

Answer (score 3):

Call it witchery, but apparently after some reboots it works ok. [Link](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=9667703).

Comment: You're a witch!

Comment: I've had this same issue.  Rebooting the iPhone seems to fix it most of the time.  I've also had better bluetooth reliability with WiFi off.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much things have changed since the newer firmwares, but for a long time bluetooth audio streaming was only possible by going around some corners and opening up audio while in the voice mail screen and other areas. The ability was then terminated once the phone locked.

I have not seen anything which would suggest that this has changed. If so, I would love to find out myself.

Comment: iPhone OS 3.0 added A2DP stereo Bluetooth. :)

Comment: Blargh, foiled!

Comment: Ah okey ... That'd be why it works for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

I use a pair of [BlueAnt Stereo Bluetooth headphones](http://www.cnet.com.au/blueant-x5-stereo-bluetooth-headset-339273871.htm) with my iPhone 3GS and don't have this problem.  I guess a headset issue?

Comment: Does it continue to play if you hit the power button?

Comment: Yep.  It works perfectly for me.

Comment: Oh, and I'm using a 3G, not 3G S.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using BT audio on my iPhone 3G since OS 3.0 came out, and it definitely seems to be a bit touchy.  I use BT audio with my car stereo, and it frequently drops when I first start playing anything.  I can generally get it back by pausing and then unpausing whatever I'm playing, although occasionally I have to disconnect and reconnect BT.  The connection seems to be very resource intensive.  It almost always has problems when the iPod app isn't running and I push "Play" on the stereo (which, ideally, will automatically start up the iPod app on the phone).  It also will sometimes break up briefly when the screen blanks or I unlock it, or if I run other apps while audio is playing.